# Datatables. How to loop through all rows and get id of each tr entry

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatable, datatables

This questions targets to `Datatables` plug-in for `JQuery`.

I need to loop through all table rows (even paginated) and get `id` of each `tr` element.

HTML table like this:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Header content 1</th>
      <th>Header content 2</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr id="etc_1_en">
      <td>Etc 1</td>
      <td>Etc 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="etc_1_ru">
      <td>Etc 3</td>
      <td>Etc 4</td>
    </tr>   
    <tr id="etc_1_fr">
      <td>Etc 5</td>
      <td>Etc 6</td>
    </tr>   
    <tr id="etc_2_en">
      <td>Foo 1</td>
      <td>Foo 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="etc_2_ru">
      <td>Foo 3</td>
      <td>Foo 4</td>
    </tr>   
    <tr id="etc_2_fr">
      <td>Foo 5</td>
      <td>Foo 6</td>
    </tr>       
  </tbody>
</table>
```

So I need to loop through each row and hide row if last 2 characters is not equal to `en` (with this checking everything fine, I'm using `substr`).

I can loop through all rows in following:

```
tbl = $('#myTable').DataTable();
var data = tbl.rows().data();

data.each(function (value, index) {
    console.log('Data in index: ' + index + ' is: ' + value);
});
```

But I can't find a way to get `id` of `tr` (with this sample data `etc_1_en`, `etc_1_ru` and so on). Could someone help me?

I've tried to pass in function `id` as parameter, but it returns - `undefined`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can loop through the `rows()` using `rows().every()`. This way you will have access to the `row` object, which will give you both `data` and `id`.

```js
tbl = $('#myTable').DataTable();

tbl.rows().every(function () {
  var data = this.data();
  var id = this.id();
  console.log('Data in id: ' + id + ' index: ' + index + ' is: ' + data);
});
```

More info: https://datatables.net/reference/api/rows().every()

Comment: Thanks for an answer, but I get an error: `row.data is not a function`

Comment: Sorry, I missed that part. I updated the answer. Basically, the `row` object doesn't work as I expected. You can do `tbl.row(index).data()` instead to get the data.

Comment: Yea, I've figured it out by adding inside loop `var row = tbl.row();`, but in this case I got printed info only about 1 row. I've tried to use your updated answer - the same, only 1 log printed to console. Also as I think there `row(index)` should be added in `var id` too, also `value` should be removed from console log. But main problem that this not loop through all rows, only first one.

Comment: Updated the answer. Basically, there's `rows().every()` method, which allows you to loop through every row and you can access the row object using `this`.

Comment: Thank your code before editing helped me, I achieved it without `every`.

Comment: I have another question related to this one, maybe you could assist me? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49151693/datatables-hide-show-multiple-rows-within-loop

Comment: I added my answer to that one.