# Datatables. Hide / Show multiple rows within loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, datatables

This questions targets to `Datatables` plug-in for `JQuery`.

I have HTML table with 3 languages `en`, `ru`, `fr`. For example if English language is chosen French and Russian entries should be hidden, if Russian language is chosen then French and English entries should be hidden and so on.

In the HTML table id looks like:

```
etc_1_en
etc_1_ru
etc_1_fr
etc_2_en
etc_2_ru
etc_2_fr
etc_3_en
etc_3_ru
etc_3_fr
...
```

But each entry have the same class: `row`

HTML table like this:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Header content 1</th>
      <th>Header content 2</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr id="etc_1_en" class="row">
      <td>Etc 1</td>
      <td>Etc 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="etc_1_ru" class="row">
      <td>Etc 3</td>
      <td>Etc 4</td>
    </tr>   
    <tr id="etc_1_fr" class="row">
      <td>Etc 5</td>
      <td>Etc 6</td>
    </tr>   
    <tr id="etc_2_en" class="row">
      <td>Foo 1</td>
      <td>Foo 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="etc_2_ru" class="row">
      <td>Foo 3</td>
      <td>Foo 4</td>
    </tr>   
    <tr id="etc_2_fr" class="row">
      <td>Foo 5</td>
      <td>Foo 6</td>
    </tr>       
  </tbody>
</table>
```

There are 3 buttons with ID like:

```
btn_id_en
btn_id_ru
btn_id_fr
```

But each button have the same class: `btn`

Here is JQuery code:

```
tbl = $('#myTable').DataTable();
var rows = tbl.rows().data();

// there looping through all entries
rows.each(function (row, index) {
    var row = tbl.row(index);
    var data = row.data();
    var id = row.id();

    // there trying to assign each row to child variable (using Datatable)
    var child = row.child;      

    if (/* some conditions */) {  // if / else conditions is working, tested with console.log();           

        // this part not working, something wrong with child maybe
        child.show();

    } else {

        // this part not working, something wrong with child maybe
        child.hide();
    }
}
```

`row.id()` returning correct ID of each row (tested via `console.log(id);`). Problem is that `hide` not working. I'm thinking that something wrong with declaring `child`.

Maybe I have to use `remove()` instead of `hide()`, but in this case how could I restore it after another button will be clicked?

Have you any ideas?

Comment: can you give the table format

Comment: try to print child to console and check what you getting.

Comment: @AbhilashRavindranCK I don't think that there HTML table will help. There is problem only with `child.hide()` and `child.show()`. Table is very simple here.

Comment: @AbhilashRavindranCK I've tried to print `child`, but this nothing says to me: `ƒ (){var d=b.apply(a,arguments);s.extend(d,d,c.methodExt);return d}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're use case is simply to have buttons then this should work:

```
var lang = ""

$.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
    function(settings, data, dataIndex) {
        var thisId = Object.keys(settings.aIds)[dataIndex].split("_")[2]
        return thisId === lang;
    }
);

var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    "language": {
        "infoFiltered": ""
    }
});

$(".filter").click(function(e) {
    lang = $(e.target).attr("id").split("_")[2];
    table.draw();
});
```

Working JSFiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/annoyingmouse/opu869ko/

Comment: Thank you, that worked! Have you ideas how could I hide this part `(filtered from 6 total entries)` if edit this number is impossible? It's possible to use `"info": false` in this case it will hide all info, but is it possible to hide only this part: `(filtered from 6 total entries)`?

Comment: @Infinity see my updated answer and JSFiddle - it's an option in the language setting, setting it to an empty string removes it.

Comment: Thank you! It helped me a lot!

Answer (score 2):

That was fun!

You need a custom filter:

```
$.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
    function(settings, data, dataIndex) {
        var langs = new Set();
        $(".filter").each(function(k, v) {
            if ($(v).is(':checked')) {
                langs.add($(v).attr("id").split("_")[2]);
            }
        });
        var thisId = Object.keys(settings.aIds)[dataIndex].split("_")[2]
        return langs.has(thisId);
    }
);
```

And I'm wary of using buttons as you'd probably need to show the hidden rows at some point so I've replaced them with checkboxes:

```
<label for="btn_id_en">
  <input class="filter" id="btn_id_en" type="checkbox" checked="checked">
  English
  </label>
<label for="btn_id_ru">
  <input class="filter" id="btn_id_ru" type="checkbox" checked="checked">
  Russian
</label>
<label for="btn_id_fr">
  <input class="filter" id="btn_id_fr" type="checkbox" checked="checked">
  French
</label>
<hr>
<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Header content 1</th>
            <th>Header content 2</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr id="etc_1_en" class="row">
            <td>Etc 1</td>
            <td>Etc 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="etc_1_ru" class="row">
            <td>Etc 3</td>
            <td>Etc 4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="etc_1_fr" class="row">
            <td>Etc 5</td>
            <td>Etc 6</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="etc_2_en" class="row">
            <td>Foo 1</td>
            <td>Foo 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="etc_2_ru" class="row">
            <td>Foo 3</td>
            <td>Foo 4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="etc_2_fr" class="row">
            <td>Foo 5</td>
            <td>Foo 6</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Working JSFiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/annoyingmouse/rus5pxms/).

Hope that helps.

Comment: This answer is more comprehensive and opens up lots of other possibilities. Ignore mine :)

Comment: Thanks for an answer, it looks like should almost did the job, but... There is wrong count of Total Entries... It shows 6, but for real it should be 2 only, just translated to 3 languages. Maybe there is ability to edit Total Entry counting?

Comment: Ah, now, you see I'd say that was the correct count unchecking one leaves this text `Showing 1 to 4 of 4 entries (filtered from 6 total entries)`, which is correct - if you start looking at pagination then things could start to go really odd, especially if you interfere with the count. I'd leave well enough alone unless you want to just remove the text which you can do with the `dom`. Alternatively, you could have multiple tables, one per language, perhaps in tabs...

Comment: User should see 1 table, with ability to change language. For use there will be only 2 entries, just translated to 3 or more languages, so if it will show total 6 entries this will be incorrect. Also there should be only 1 table, not 3 separate. How about `dom`? What can be done?

Comment: @annoyingmouse and could you help me to achieve it using buttons, not checkboxes? There never will be ability to select multiple languages.

Comment: @Infinity added a further answer using just buttons. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

`child` is not a variable but a function. Replacing:

```
var child = row.child;
```

with

```
var child = row.child();
```

should fix it.

See here: https://datatables.net/reference/api/row().child().hide()

Comment: Thanks for an answer. In this case I got an error: `Cannot read property 'hide' of undefined`. As per documentation: `jQuery object with the child rows for the parent row in its result set, or undefined if there are no child rows set for the parent yet.` It looks like row is not child. Have you ideas, how to figure it out?