# hi, I have an issue in Jquery when I'm looping through Datatable paginated table, from 11th row, its not looping

Tags: jquery, loops, datatables

my table body is show below

```
 <tbody id="processBody" class="">
   <tr data-status="pending" > ----- </tr>
```

and in Jquery,

```
$("#processBody").find("tr[data-status]").each(function () {
     console.log(this)
     var process_status = $(this).data('status');
});
```

will outputs only first ten rows, i.e, tr elements, but its not looping from 11th row.
I'm not sure, but I think since its paginated with jquery's Datatables, from 11th tr row, its not looping and not displaying the Table Tr elements

Comment: Please create a [MRE] within your question. Your PHP code is irrelevant. Show us the rendered HTML.

Comment: It's very hard to tell what is happening in your case without minimal reproducible example. But note that jquery works on DOM. And you are using pagination. So it may be possible that there will be only 10 rows in DOM when you are running your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thankfully I found solution, link below

https://stackoverflow.com/a/49148001/13437588

to loop through a paginated table, below is the code, where I needed to access all data attribute of each  element

table with id = example2
and table row with data attribut as follows

```
<tr data-status = "pending"> ... </tr>
<tr data-status = "progress"> ...</tr>
 <tr > .... </tr>



  var table = $('#example2').DataTable();
    table.rows().eq(0).each( function ( index ) {
    var process_status = $( this.row( index ).node() ).attr( 'data-status' )
    });
```